# Choosing bootloader for Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu alongside windows 7 on a separate SSD.

Windows 7 is installed on my first SSD (sda), then I have two further HDDs for data (sdb and sdc) and on the second SSD (sdd) I want to install Ubuntu.

I have chosen "something else" in the installation but now I don't know, which device to choose for the bootloader. I've searched in the internet but I onlt find answers for a situation where Windows and Ubuntu are installed on the same drive.

What makes me wonder is the following entry in the list for the boot loader devices:

```
/dev/sdc1 Windows 7 (loader)
```

I'm wondering why the loader is on sdc instead of sda (I've installed Windows on sda but that was already some years ago so I don't fully remember what I did exactly)

Here's some further information from parted:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA M4-CT128M4SSD2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  128GB  128GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   2000GB  2000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: ATA SAMSUNG HD103SJ (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs         boot


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  246GB  246GB  primary  ntfs


Model: Generic Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 4038MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4038MB  4037MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since sda is MBR(msdos) partitioned, Windows is the old BIOS/MBR boot. And then you want Ubuntu installed in BIOS boot, but have boot loader in same drive as Ubuntu, and keep Windows boot loader on Windows drive.

Only if installing to sdb which is gpt partitioned, you will also need a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag.

Just use Something Else install option and choose correct drive (not partition) on the partitioning screen. Do not use any auto install option as that will install grub to drive seen as sda, overwriting your Windows boot loader.

If no Windows skip those screens, but partitioning screenshot shows combo box at bottom for drive to install grub bootloader, choose sdd if that is drive you are installing into:

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

After install set BIOS to boot from drive you installed Ubuntu, or sdd. But it will show drive by brand/model not sdd.